# Receiving a nillable element from a .NET webservice using Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, web-services

I have a .NET webservice sitting on my local IIS.  I'm calling 1 method from it, ClientSearch, using a Blackberry.  The method is:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Client> ClientSearch(string Surname, string Forename, string DOB, string Postcode)
{
   List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
   // Populate list
   return clients;
}
```

When I call this from my Blackberry simulator I get the error:
*"not nillable element of array type in response is missed".*

I'm accessing the webservice using stubs generated by the Sun Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2.  The wsdl file for the client type contains: 
`<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Client" nillable="true" type="tns:Client" />`

This is where the nillable comes from but the values are hardcoded in the web method so it should always have a value.

The code i'm using to call the webservice is the same as I use in every BB app to call them so I know that it works.

```
Service1Soap_Stub stub = new Service1Soap_Stub();
result = stub.clientSearch("", "", "", "");
```

I'm using Eclipse 3.4.0 (Ganymede) and the Blackberry JDE Plug-in 1.0.0.67 and component pack 4.5.0.

I've seen this on a few different forums but can't find how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem.  The issue is that my Client object had some public properties that were never assigned a value too.  I thought they would have the default values for their type but that wasn't the case.